# ipad rotation hides elements in view !

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, rotation, screen-rotation

OK here is a very basic iPad app that i am starting out with and I am already into issue. I have been doing iphone apps but in that too never implemented rotation things.. well here is the issue. This is a simple viewbased app build with interface builder that looks like this:

[image]

when i run the app, the vertical orientation has both elements like this :

[image]

However, when the orientation changes to horizontal, the app hides the label which is at the top.. :
[image]

Suggestions please !

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, select the label, then open the size inspector and in Autosizing section make the label stick to the upper edge of the window. You may also need to stick it to the left and/or right edge and make it change the width - depending on how you want it to be resized when orientation changes.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and I did as you suggested to BOTH my elements (tried with just the label too but result is same). Now the service catalog image goes below.. the screen shorts are at http://img715.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20100923at417.png/ and http://img121.imageshack.us/i/screenkxe.png/

Comment: Try just the top edge for the label (i.e. only activate the top I instead of all 4 you have now) and the bottom edge for the button. Or top-left for the label, bottom-left for the button. Experiment a little - you can usually achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: no luck but the same situation.. any online example that you can point me to please?

Comment: Have you tried changing the auto-resize settings? I couldn't quite reproduce your problem - in my version it is the button that gets moved off the screen :) - but it could be solved by changing the auto-resize settings from being attached to top-left edges (default) to just the left edge.